# Django uploading/downloading multiple files

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Using Django 2.0

What i'm trying to do is post a link for each file uploaded. But my problem is that when I upload multiple files, the field only takes the last one.

So long I have tried this:

In my CBV

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('Resource_file')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                f.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

in my forms.py

```
Resource_file = forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.FileInput(attrs= {
            "multiple": True,
        }
        ),
        required = False
    )
```

for example 6 files were uploaded and saved on my media root yet only [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSEuu.png) is related with the field...

How can I save multiple files and display each one on my template?
Extra: How can I verify the file extension when displaying them on my template? I would like to make like an icon for each type of file.